# How much limits google api has?

Tags: android, api, maps, android-maps-v2

As in documentation it is said that there is 2500 per day. My doubt is whether this 2500 limit is for all the user who downloaded the same application from play store or for each user it is 2500?

Answer (score 0):

It's 2500 for all users who are using your application, combined.